# Normal model matrix calculation for normal mapping in GLSL

Tags: opengl, matrix, glsl

I need to calculate a normal model matrix for doing normal mapping in GLSL shader. I want to make sure I am right on this: When I multiply view (camera model) matrix with geometry model matrix, is the view matrix supposed to be already inverted? It is not clear from the online examples like those found [here](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial26/tutorial26.html) and [here](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-13-normal-mapping/). Also, I see in some cases people also transpose the resulting matrix. Why? So what is the right way to build a normal model matrix in OpenGL?

Currently I do it this way:

```
glm::mat4 view = inverse(GetCameraModel());
glm::mat3 normalModelMatr= glm::mat3(view * mesh.GetModel());
```

Is this the way to go ?

Comment: You're waaaaay below the character limit.  Add some spaces between your sentences.

Comment: What is wrong now with my question ?

Comment: Presentation and readability.

Comment: Can't see any problem with readability. Also everyone is welcomed to format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct normal matrix is the inverse transpose of the model-view matrix. If you do not do any non-uniform scaling, that is scaling axises by different amounts, the inverse of the matrix is equal to its transpose because it is [orthogonal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix). 
Therefore, the two operations cancel out and it is just the original matrix.

If you do do non uniform scale, the matrix is not orthogonal and you must do the inverse transpose.

You take the top 3x3 matrix, because you only need to rotate and scale normals, not translate.

So your normal matrix is correct as long as you do not employ non-uniform scaling.

Comment: So from what you wrote I should imply that it's better do transposition anyway to cover cases where non uniform scaling is done?

Comment: @MichaelIV No. Because in the case where it isn't necessary, you take an unneeded performance hit. Non uniform scaling is very rare in practice, but I wanted you to be aware of its implications.

Comment: Also you meant to say " if you don't do any non uniform scaling, that's scaling all axis by the same amount ..." ?

Comment: My wording got a little weird there ... I'll edit. But yes basically if you scale and dont want to have to do the inverse transpose, you must scale the same amount along each axis.

Comment: You wrote, you take top 3x3 matrix, of original matrix or of inverse transposed?

Comment: @bobenko inverse transposed. But as noted, it is equivalent to the original matrix if no non-uniform scaling was done.